# Not found tab jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a mistake in the tabs donot they should want I could help out with the following script that is made based on jQuery.

```
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(this).closest(".tabs-menu").next(".tab").find(".tab-content").parent().not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xqvgxqxd/

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using jQuery UI Tabs instead? http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: You're fading the tabs in but never hiding them. Is that your problem?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/Ps16qRzzyV